# ACCESS 2010 Navigation Form Query Property

Tags: forms, ms-access, properties, navigation

I'm coming accross a problem and i have searched the entire World Wide Web:

I have a Navigation form which has forms in it.
Those forms are used to give properties to my queries.

For example:

FormStatus-->Ask user to select the status and shoot the value to the query.

These queries build reports.

The main problem is that now that my form is in a navigation form, the link for the property is no longer working.

The link used to be : `Forms!myForm!myProperty`

Now i tried

```
Forms!navigationForm!myForm!myProperty
Me!myForm!myProperty
Forms!ParentForm!SubForm.Form!FieldName
```

Nothing works out!! Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

As a general approach to filtering forms or reports, as you can see placing forms! references inside of forms becomes a rather messy business real fast here.

You are best to remove the forms! references from ALL your queries. You then build a form that the user enter the values into, and then execute a browseto command.

The problem you are experiencing here is that the new navigation form swaps out a given form for a new form. This means that the old form is NOT loaded anymore. So, either you

Plan A

Dump use of forms! commands in your SQL queries. This is a good idea anyway since then one query will not blow up because some silly form is not open. And more important the query can be used in other places in the application without fear of some form not being opened.

The instant you place a forms! reference inside of a query is the instant you ruin that query and force "marry" that query to one form that must be opened.

Plan b:

Dump the use of the new navigation control system. Just remember, the new navigation system does NOT load the next form, but "replaces" the one that is being displayed. Thus the previous form is not going to be loaded anymore and thus no forms! ref is allowed. Worse, since the navigation form is really using sub-forms, then the forms! references have to be changed.

You can certainly grab the values of controls and build a where clause in code and use that for openform or open report commands here.

Last but not least, if you in for lots of continued torture, you can stick with your poor design you have now and simply re-edit and fix all of the forms! references to reflect that they are now being used inside of a parent form, and all of your forms are now in effect being run as sub forms.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dot instead of `!` before the property  `Forms!navigationForm!myForm.myProperty`