# Microsoft Access - Navigation form is causing my query to not work

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I got a form that works amazingly by itself, but the second I attach it to my navigation form. I start to get prompted for user input since this line

`[Forms]![frm_addReceiveReportInformation]![cbo_PurchaseOrderID]`

no longer works due to the current form becoming subform in the navigation form which was explained in 
[ACCESS 2010 Navigation Form Query Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405547/access-2010-navigation-form-query-property?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I can't seem to figure a way out of using the !form since I absolutely need to retrieve the ID from a combo box to update another combo box.

I tried multiple ways of using the !forms but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to retrieve my information that I am seeking.

I got the 2 way navigation menu(vertical + horizontal tabs). Anyone got advice or has encounter this problem in the pass, who can direct me down the right path.

[image]

Comment: Where is the code that references that combobox? If it's in 'frm_addReceiveReportInformation' why not just reference as 'Me.cbo_PurchaseOrderID'?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn its directly in the query for the other combo box.

Comment: I need clarification on where everything is located. You had a form named 'frm_addReceiveReportInformation' that worked just great. Now you have made it a subform and it doesn't work. Are both comboboxes on the subform, or is one on the parent form? And which combobox doesn't work?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn the form isn't a subform, but when you attach it to a navigation form, it technically becomes a subform. sorry for the badly worded description on my part. Both combo box are on the same form. I added a picture to the main post.

Comment: The Part Code CBO rely off the ID from PO No. CBO.

Comment: You need to modify the query source to be like:  [Forms]![frmParentForm]![MySubForm].[Form]![cbo_PurchaseOrderID]   Will the form ever be used as 'stand alone' or will it always be as a subform on your navigation form?

Comment: it is used currently as both... but I think I might be force to create a frm_navReceivingReportInformation version of it. Unless there is a way around it?

Comment: You can add code in your form to test if it is a subform and set the rowsource of the combobox as needed.  i.e. On Error Resume Next
Dim strParent   As String
strParent = Me.Parent.Name

If Err.Number = 0 Then          ' Parent form is open
    Me.cboChild2.RowSource = "..."
ElseIf Err.Number = 2452 Then       ' Parent not open
    Me.cboChild2.RowSource = "..."
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a field inside a form, which is attached to a navigation tab, you should use the following structure:

```
[Forms]![YourNavigationTab]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![YourField]
```

Note: tested in MS Access 2013

Answer (score 0):

In order for queries that contain form references to work, the form must be fully loaded.  I think the problem you are experiencing is that the query in the Row Source of the Part Code combo is being evaluated before the form is loaded and therefore you are being asked to input the parameter value.

You can work around this by leaving the Row Source property of the Part Code combo empty until it gets focus for the first time, something like:

```
Private Sub cboPartCode_GotFocus()
  If Len(cboPartCode.RowSource) = 0 Then
    cboPartCode.[RowSource] = "Your Query"
    cboPartCode.Requery
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Its not on load, its after I select my PO number from the first combo box, since its in the navigation form. it cannot retrieve the ID anymore.

Comment: Can you show me the entire query? Is the query in the first combo or second?

Comment: its in the second one.

`SELECT tbl_rawItemList.ID, tbl_rawItemList.ItemSerialCode, [yarnType] & " " & [yarnSize] & " " & [colour] & " " & [description] AS [Desc]
FROM tbl_rawItemList INNER JOIN tbl_PODetails ON tbl_rawItemList.ID = tbl_PODetails.rawItemListID
WHERE (((tbl_PODetails.purchaseOrderID)=[Forms]![frm_mainNavigation]![frm_addReceiveReportInformation].[form]![cbo_PurchaseOrderID]))
ORDER BY tbl_rawItemList.ItemSerialCode;
`

Comment: I noticed you are employing the SubForm syntax now. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes just put a button on the navigation form which opens the desired form as a standalone form. It is probably not the neatest solution but it does work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).